# $\exists$ $a, b, \in \mathbb{F}$ such that $a^2 + b^2 = 2ab = 0$ $\implies$ Char($\mathbb{F}$) $= 2$.

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

Consider a field $\mathbb{F}$.

If there exist elements $a, b \in \mathbb{F}$, not both zero, such that $a^2 + b^2 = 0$ and $2ab = 0$, then I need to show that the characteristic of $\mathbb{F}$ is $2$.

How can I approach is problem ? I am clueless.

Comment: Is it possible that exactly one of them is nonzero?

Comment: If $ab\neq0$ and $2ab=0$, then the characteric is $2$. So show that $ab\neq0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your hypothesis follows $(a+b)^2 = (a-b)^2 = 0$, whence $a+b = a-b = 0$. It follows that $a = b$ and $0 = a+ a = (1+1)a$ and finally $1+1 = 0$ since $(a, a) = (a, b) \not=(0, 0)$.